# How to replace the value in script using WIX

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.5, wix-extension, wixlib

I have SQL Script and executing that script as part of MSI Intallation using WIX Tool. Now I would like to declare a variable in the script and want to replace the variable value from Include file variable value.

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE $(tablename) (Value1 CHAR(50), Value2 INTEGER)
```

Include.wxi

```
<?define tablename = "Test" ?>
```

Now I want to replace the `$(tablename)` value with `Test` which is declared in Include file. can you help me how can I achive this

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(var.tablename)`.

For reference, see http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm

Comment: @nag_ mittapalli, has this helped you? i have a similar problem, but i want to use properties.

Comment: @osiris, this syntax is for pre-processor variables (evaluated at build time). If you want to use properties (evaluated during install), then you need to use the [property] syntax.